# async pipe with a method call in angular 4 calls infinitely

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap, angular-pipe

I need to provide select UI element with dynamic options for which I have a method that returns an observable based on the Inputs

**TypeScript (Component class)**

```
getCars(type : string, engine : string) : Observable<Cars>{
    return this.carService.getCars(type,engine);
}
```

In the HTML I make my element call this method for data

**Html (Template file)**

```
<ng-select [items]="getCars(type,engine) | async"
    bindLabel="value"
    bindValue="id"
</ng-select>
```

but this results in service being called infinitely. I do not want to use ngOnInit as I need the observable to be dynamically assigned

I'm using [this UI element for select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the expected behavior, and how angular change detection works, it's not a good idea to call method from the view and use a property instead

```
this.cars = getCars(type,engine)
```

Comment: Yup true I had it worked in a different way though:Observable<car> and then

Answer (score 1):

I achived it by calling this method to change the observable variable

in **Component**

```
    car$:Observable<cars> 
getCars(type : string, engine : string) {
    this.car$=this.carService.getCars(type,engine);
}
```

in **Template**

```
<ng-select [items]="car$ | async"
    (focus)="getCars(type,engine)"
    bindLabel="value"
    bindValue="id"
</ng-select>
```